# How do make gradient colored Qr Code in LaTex?

Tags: color, gradient, qrcode

I am using the qrcode package and I know how to make plain colored qr codes:

> \usepackage{qrcode}[]
>
> \color{blue}{\qrcode[height=7cm]{site qr code}}

but I want to make with gradient colors, How to do this? This is what I want:

[image]

Comment: If I were you I'd generate the QR code and use Gimp or another image editing software for something like this. If you insist on doing this within latex then here are a few starting pointers: 1. The package uses simple `\rule` to generate the white and black squares in the matrix (see line 891 in the .dtx file) 2. You could use `etoolbox` package to edit the relevant lines and replace the rule with a tikzrule. 3. The tikzrule gradient would have to depend on the line of the square in the matrix.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the solution from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/344271/241149) and use the qr code command instead of text as input for the newly created `fadingtext` command

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{qrcode}[]
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings, shadings}
\newcounter{fadcnt}\setcounter{fadcnt}{0}
\newcommand\fadingtext[3][]{%
\stepcounter{fadcnt}
  \begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=fading letter\thefadcnt]
    \node[text=transparent!0,inner xsep=0pt,outer xsep=0pt,#1] {#3};
  \end{tikzfadingfrompicture}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(textnode.base)]
    \node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,#1](textnode){\phantom{#3}}; 
    \shade[path fading=fading letter\thefadcnt,#2,fit fading=false]
    (textnode.south west) rectangle (textnode.north east);% 
  \end{tikzpicture}% 
}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newbox\shbox
\tikzset{%
  path picture shading/.style={%
  path picture={%
%
\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{path picture bounding box}{south west}}%
  {\pgfpointanchor{path picture bounding box}{north east}}%
\pgfgetlastxy\pathwidth\pathheight%
\pgfinterruptpicture%
   \global\setbox\shbox=\hbox{\pgfuseshading{#1}}%
 \endpgfinterruptpicture%
\pgftransformshift{\pgfpointanchor{path picture bounding box}{center}}%
\pgftransformxscale{\pathwidth/(\wd\shbox)}%
\pgftransformyscale{\pathheight/(\ht\shbox)}% \dp will (should) be 0pt
\pgftext{\box\shbox}%
%
    }
  }
}
\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{rainbow}{10bp}{color(0bp)=(violet);
            color(1.6667bp)=(blue);
            color(3.3333bp)=(cyan);
            color(5bp)=(green);
            color(6.6667bp)=(yellow);
            color(8.3333bp)=(orange);
            color(10bp)=(red)}
\pgfdeclareverticalshading{rainbow_vertical}{10bp}{color(0bp)=(violet);
            color(1.6667bp)=(blue);
            color(3.3333bp)=(cyan);
            color(5bp)=(green);
            color(6.6667bp)=(yellow);
            color(8.3333bp)=(orange);
            color(10bp)=(red)}
\begin{document} 
\noindent
\fadingtext[scale=1]{upper left=red, upper right=green, lower left=blue,lower right=yellow}{\qrcode[height=5cm]{site qr code}}
\fadingtext[scale=1]{path picture shading=rainbow}{\qrcode[height=5cm]{site qr code}}
\fadingtext[scale=1]{path picture shading=rainbow_vertical}{\qrcode[height=5cm]{site qr code}}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: I do not know why, but it does not work properly in overleaf...