# How can I define a more "complex" font color?

Tags: fonts, graphics, color, titles

I am trying to define the font color for a title  and I want to set some more complex color like the one that is shown in the picture below: [image]

I know how to select a single color at a time however is there any way to create text like the one above using Latex? Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Does [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/344271/2417) help?

Comment: Or the package chickenize.